# subgroups of a connected solvable group consisting of semi-simple elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In Humphreys' linear algebraic groups, section 19.4, it says that:

Let $G$ be a connected solvable algebraic group and $H$ an abstract commutative subgroup of $G$ consisting of semi-simple elements, then $H$ must be included in a torus.

Is there a counter-example when $G$ is connected but not solvable?

Thank you.